# Years separated by comma CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a field called StartYear, the value of my field is 2000. I have another field called EndYear, the value of my field is 2005.

I want to create a field called YearsInTheProgram that has the values 2005,2004, 2003,2002,2001,2000.

Each of my rows have different values, so in essence I would like this field to have the difference of my fields separated my commas.

I was able to find something that would work, but this would give me a value in different rows. However, I want all of them in one row.

```
with  CTE as
        (
        select  datepart(year, '2006-12-25') as yr
        union all
        select  yr + 1
        from    CTE
        where   yr < datepart(year, '2013-11-14')
        )
select  yr
from    CTE
```

Comment: One should almost never store a delimited list in a column, why are start/end years not enough on their own?

Comment: Because I need to use a filter afterwards to get my results. I need the results in between to create a different process.

Comment: So you are querying for rows that you want to pivot into a column and then filter on the column string? But why not just filter the rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tmp varchar(250)
SET @tmp = ''

;with  CTE as
        (
        select  datepart(year, '2006-12-25') as yr
        union all
        select  yr + 1
        from    CTE
        where   yr < datepart(year, '2013-11-14')
        )

select @tmp = @tmp + convert(varchar(500), yr) + ', ' from CTE
select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp)) as yr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bulid up your string of years using this CTE.

```
DECLARE @STARTYEAR varchar(10) = '2006-12-25'
DECLARE @ENDYEAR varchar(10) = '2013-11-14'

;with  CTE as
        (
        select  datepart(year, @STARTYEAR) as yr, CAST(datepart(year, @STARTYEAR) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as c
        union all
        select  yr + 1 as yr, CAST(concat(c, ',', yr+1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as c
        from    CTE
        where   yr < datepart(year, @ENDYEAR)
        )
select  yr, c
from    CTE
where (yr = datepart(year, @ENDYEAR))
```

And here it is with StartYear and EndYear taken from DB table.

```
create table #yr (id int, start varchar(20), stop varchar(20))
insert into #yr values(1,'2005-01-01','2010-12-10'), (2,'2008-01-01','2011-12-10'), (3,'2007-01-01','2013-12-10'), (4,'2009-01-01','2012-10-10')

;with  CTE as
        (
        select  start as start, datepart(year, start) as yr, CAST(datepart(year, start) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as c from #yr
        union all
        select  CTE.start as start, yr + 1 as yr, CAST(concat(c, ',', yr+1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as c
        from    CTE join #yr on #yr.start = CTE.start
        where   yr < datepart(year, stop)
        )
select  id, #yr.start, #yr.stop, c
from    CTE join #yr on #yr.start = CTE.start
where (yr = datepart(year, stop))
```

With following result

```
4   2009-01-01  2012-10-10  2009,2010,2011,2012
3   2007-01-01  2013-12-10  2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013
2   2008-01-01  2011-12-10  2008,2009,2010,2011
1   2005-01-01  2010-12-10  2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010
```