# Dynamic values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, cross-join

MasterInput-1

| Location | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| India | 2.3 | 2.4 | 2.4 | 2.4 |
| Australia | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.3 | 1.3 |

Input-2

| S No | Name | Location | YearMonth | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | India | Mar-22 | 2.060 |
| 2 | A2 | India | Jun-22 | 1.547 |
| 3 | A3 | India | Jan-23 | 0.790 |
| 4 | A4 | India | Jul-21 | 3.080 |
| 5 | A5 | Australia | Oct-22 | 2.745 |
| 6 | A6 | Australia | Mar-21 | 1.823 |
| 7 | A7 | Australia | Sep-21 | 14.350 |
| 8 | A8 | Australia | Aug-22 | 0.621 |

InterimCalcualation

| S No | Name | Location | YearMonth | Value | Value 2023 | Value 2022 | Value 2021 | Value 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | India | Mar-22 | 2.060 | 4.944 | 4.944 | 4.944 | 4.738 |
| 2 | A2 | India | Jun-22 | 1.547 | 3.712 | 3.712 | 3.712 | 3.558 |
| 3 | A3 | India | Jan-23 | 0.790 | 1.895 | 1.895 | 1.895 | 1.816 |
| 4 | A4 | India | Jul-21 | 3.080 | 7.392 | 7.392 | 7.392 | 7.084 |
| 5 | A5 | Australia | Oct-22 | 2.745 | 3.568 | 3.568 | 3.568 | 3.294 |
| 6 | A6 | Australia | Mar-21 | 1.823 | 2.370 | 2.370 | 2.370 | 2.188 |
| 7 | A7 | Australia | Sep-21 | 14.350 | 18.655 | 18.655 | 18.655 | 17.220 |
| 8 | A8 | Australia | Aug-22 | 0.621 | 0.807 | 0.807 | 0.807 | 0.745 |

FinalOutput

| Year | FinalValue |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 40.642 |
| 2021 | 43.344 |
| 2022 | 43.344 |
| 2023 | 43.344 |

```
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) 
,LocationName VARCHAR(50)
,YearName   INT
,CBValue FLOAT
)

CREATE TABLE MasterMigration
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,AppName VARCHAR(50)
,LocationName VARCHAR(50)
,YearMigrated INT
,MigValue FLOAT
)

INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A1','India',2022,2.06)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A2','India',2022,1.547)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A3','India',2023,0.79)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A4','India',2021,3.08)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A5','Australia',2022,2.745)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A6','Australia',2021,1.823)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A7','Australia',2021,14.35)
INSERT into MasterMigration VALUES('A8','Australia',2022,0.621)


INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('India',2020,2.3)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('India',2021,2.4)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('India',2022,2.4)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('India',2023,2.4)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('Australia',2020,1.2)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('Australia',2021,1.3)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('Australia',2022,1.3)
INSERT INTO MAsterLocation VALUES('Australia',2023,1.3)

DECLARE @EndLoop INT
,@StartLoop INT
,@Diff INT
,@StartYear INT 
SELECT @StartYear=MIN(YearMigrated) 
FROM MasterMigration
SET @Diff=DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) -@StartYear
    SET @StartLoop=@Diff+1
    SET @EndLoop=0

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#YearDimension') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE #YearDimension


IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#InterimOutput') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE #InterimOutput
CREATE TABLE #YearDimension
(
YearID INT
)
WHILE @StartLoop >= @EndLoop
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #YearDimension
    SELECT DATEPART (yyyy,DATEADD(YEAR, -@StartLoop, GETDATE())) X
    SET @StartLoop=@StartLoop-1
END


--SELECT * FROM #YearDimension

SELECT *
INTO #InterimOutput
FROM (
SELECT AppName,X.LocationName,Yearmigrated,MigValue,YearID,YearNAme,CBValue,(MigValue*CBValue)FinalValue 
FROM MasterMigration X
CROSS APPLY #YearDimension Y
JOIN MasterLOcation Z
ON X.LocationName=Z.LocationName
AND Y.YearID=Z.YearName
)MM
```

and finally:

```
-- SELECT * FROM #InterimOutput

SELECT YearID,SUM(FInalValue) FV
FROM #InterimOutput
GROUP BY YearID
--ORDER BY APPNAMEx
```

Final Output Years Logic : based on minyear to current Year..

It will be dynamic and MasterMigration contains many records.

Is there any better way to get the outputs when we have huge records..Any alternate design which helps for easy retrieval.. Pls help..

Comment: which database system are you using and please add your attempt, that looks like a homework question so we expect that you az least try it

Comment: I am using SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can put all in one got, but the following needs SQL Server 2022 for generate_series, where it was finally implemented.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT 
--  AppName
--  ,X.LocationName
--  ,Yearmigrated
--  ,MigValue
    --,
  YearID
--  ,[YearName]
--  ,CBValue
    ,(MigValue*CBValue)FinalValue 
FROM MasterMigration X
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value as YearID 
FROM GENERATE_SERIES((SELECT MIN(YearMigrated) 
FROM MasterMigration
) - 1, DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) +1)) Y
JOIN MasterLocation Z
ON X.LocationName = Z.LocationName 
  AND Y.[YearID] = Z.YearName)
SELECT YearID,SUM(FInalValue) FV
FROM CTE
GROUP BY YearID
```

| YearID | FV |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 40.6439 |
| 2021 | 43.3455 |
| 2022 | 43.3455 |
| 2023 | 43.3455 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jHNYDmX7)

If you have an older version, then you can make another prior recursive CTE to get your year see [Years separated by comma CTE in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763548/years-separated-by-comma-cte-in-sql-server)